# For which topological spaces X does an exponential object Y^X exist for all "nice" topological spaces Y?

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is exponentiable, meaning that that an exponential object $Y^X$ exists for every topological space $Y$, iff $X$ is core-compact.

However, in the only proof I know of that non-core-compact spaces are non-exponentiable (here: http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/newyork.pdf), the counterexample given is that there is no exponential object $\mathbb{S}^X$, where $\mathbb{S}$ is Sierpinski space, which is a kind of strange topological space.

Are there known theorems of the form "If (and possibly only if) $X$ satisfies some property P (weaker than core-compactness), then an exponential object $Y^X$ exists for every space $Y$ in some class $\mathcal{C}$ of nice topological spaces"? Alternatively, is it known that even for certain narrow classes $\mathcal{C}$ of topological spaces, if an exponential object $Y^X$ exists for every $Y\in\mathcal{C}$, then $X$ must be core-compact?

Comment: Well, for instance, if you require $Y$ to be Hausdorff, then $Y^X$ exists for any space $X$ with no non-constant maps to a Hausdorff space (namely, $Y^X=Y$).  So if you are imposing some niceness conditions on $Y$, you will probably want to also impose conditions on $X$ saying that $X$ is nice enough to be able to have nontrivial maps to $Y$ in order to avoid trivialities.  That's why the Sierpinski space is a natural choice of $Y$ here: every space has "enough" maps to it.